# "Expect of someone" vs. "expect from someone"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the following questions?

> What do you expect **of** your partner.
>
> What do you expect **from** your partner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **[of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)**, I think that this is the most relevant meaning:

> typical or characteristic of

For **[from](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from)**:

> used to show the place where someone or something starts

What you expect **of** somebody relates to the way they are, and the way that they behave, without reference to your involvement in that behaviour.

What you expect **from** somebody relates to what you personally get from them, both in terms of material things and their behaviour.

Comment: and [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/expect-from-expect-of.2994779/) (external) thread backs up your answer